# numpy - one array calculates the average based on the position of another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays with the same shape. If the value of the element of the `bList` array corresponding to the `aList` array is 255, then find the corresponding position in the `aList` array, and add the eligible elements of the `a` array to calculate the average.

I think I can do it with loop but I think it's stupid.

```
import numpy as np

aList = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
bList = np.array([[255,255,0,255], [0,0,255,255], [255,0,0,0]])
sum_list = []
for id,row in enumerate(aList):
    for index,ele in enumerate(row):
        if bList[id][index]==255:
            tmp = aList[id][index]
            sum_list.append(tmp)
average = np.mean(sum_list) #(1+2+4+7+8+9)/6 #5.166666666666667
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, you should make that an answer so it can be rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
np.mean(aList[np.where(bList==255)])
```

Or with a boolean mask:

```
mask = (bList==255)

(aList*mask).sum()/mask.sum()
```

Output: `5.166666666666667`